# New Shopify session token drive me crazy

Tags: shopify, react-apollo, koa, shopify-app

I tried to simply upgrade this https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-demo-app-node-react
to use session token instead of cookies on Shopify.
So i followed this guide https://github.com/Shopify/koa-shopify-auth `Migrating from cookie-based authentication to session tokens`

Now my app look like :

server.js

```
 router.get("(.*)", verifyRequest({ accessMode: "offline" }), handleRequest); // Everything else must have sessions
```

_app.js

```
function MyProvider(props) {
  const app = useAppBridge();

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    fetch: authenticatedFetch(app),
    fetchOptions: {
      credentials: "include"
    }
  });


  const Component = props.Component;

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}


class MyApp extends App {

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, shopOrigin } = this.props;

    const config = {
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      shopOrigin: shopOrigin,
      forceRedirect: true
    };

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Head>
          <title>Shopy</title>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        </Head>
        <Provider config={config}>
          <ClientRouter />
          <AppProvider i18n={translations}>
            <MyProvider Component={Component}>
            </MyProvider>
          </AppProvider>
        </Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
  return {
    shopOrigin: ctx.query.shop
  };
};
```

So the problem is with apollo , i got an error `Error: Network error: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0` and in my ngrok i got `GET /auth                          400 Bad Request`

Normally `authenticatedFetch(app)` should authenticate my graphql request , but its always hitting the `/auth`

If someone have an idea or a working example of sessions token based on github react app i would be glad